# Qt/C++: interrupt QProcess arbitrarily with button (simulate ^c)

Tags: android, c++, qt, adb, logcat

So I need to make a Qt Application (with GUI) that executes the "adb logcat" command (it's a log that keeps being generated until ^c is pressed).
I need a GUI button to make the process stop and pass the output to a Text Browser.
This is the code I use to get the QProcess output:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("adb logcat");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
QByteArray logcatOut = process.readAllStandardOutput();
ui->devicesOutput->setText(logcatOut);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

process.waitForFinished(-1);

would prevent your program of being executed further, till the process "adb" has finished.
So your GUI will be frozen.

1. You should define QProcess process as a class variable. Use QProcess
   *process; instead of creating it on stack. (Best practice for all QObject derivates)
2. Declare a slot which handles clicked-signal of your button.
3. call process->terminate() in the slot.

Comment: I have tried commenting process.waitForFinished(-1); in other simpler commands (adb devices) but what happens is that for some reason the text is not passed to the Text Browser, the console says when I press the button: "QProcess: Destroyed while process ("adb") is still running."

Comment: @GabMus: Please implement point 1 of my answer! You should use: process = new QProcess( this ); process->start("adb logcat"); ... Where process is defined in the .h-file of your GUI as: QProcess *process; In your example you create process object on stack (dont do it with QObjects!) and so the process-object is deleted as soon as the execution leaves the scope. Try to understand the terms "heap" and "stack" and what it means to create variables on heap and on stack

Comment: > Use QProcess *process; instead of creating it on stack. (Best practice for all QObject derivates) NO, There is no such best practice at all. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

use [QProcess::terminate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#terminate) to stop running app